# Replacing hyperlinks in HTML with Powershell

Tags: html, powershell

I have the following single page HTML:
http://calibur.5gbfree.com/ORIGINAL.html
This page loads up images hosted elsewhere.

I'm trying to replace every URL starting with a "https://www.fanaitcal.com" with "http://www.dontcensor.net/links/8733666/type/dlg/https://www.fanatical.com"

This is the code I've got so far:

```
$test = get-content 'C:\temp\HTMLs\Output\ORIGINAL.html'
$test.Replace('"https://www.fanatical.com','"http://www.anrdoezrs.net/links/8733666/type/dlg/https://www.fanatical.com') | Set-Content C:\temp\htmls\output\REPLACED.html -Force
```

This works perfectly fine as long as I run the the HTML file locally.
But if once I upload it to a hosting service the images and links are messed up as you can see here:

http://calibur.5gbfree.com/REPLACED.html

Comment: I don't see issues with pictures in the REPLACED html? Can you show an image of what you see? Solution might be here http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Something with my Adguard was skewing the results. After removing that junk the urls now show up perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Again, Adguard interfering with my work.
I uninstalled it entirely and now the links show up perfectly fine.

Cheers